# extract information from p tag and insert into dict python with beautifulsoap

Tags: python, html, dictionary, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web scrape a government public page that contains speeches and biography of ministers. At the end I would like a dictionary like this:

```
data = {

    { "time": "18/05/2016",
    "author_speech": name
    "bio": [list, of, paragraphs_bio]
    "speech": [list, of, paragraphs_speech]
    "bio_link": "url"
    "speech_link": "url"
    }
    { "time": "01/01/2011",
    "author_speech": "name"
    "bio": [list, of, paragraphs]
    "speech": [list, of, paragraphs]
    "bio_link": "url"
    "speech_link": "url"
    }


}
```

Page example

```
<div class="item-page">
   <p><strong>TITLE</strong></p>
   <p><strong>18/05/2016</strong>&nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="/link//paragraphs/bio">Author's name</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="/link/paragraphs/speech">Speech</a></p>
   <p><strong>01/01/2011&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</strong><a href="/link/paragraphs/bio02">Author's name02</a></p>
   <p><strong>28/08/2013&nbsp; &nbsp; </strong><a href="/link/paragraphs/bio03">Author's name03</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="/link/paragraphs/speech">Speech</a></p>
   <p><strong>01/01/2011&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</strong><a href="/link/paragraphs/bio04">Author's name04</a></p>
   <p><strong>01/01/2011&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</strong><a href="/link/paragraphs/bio05">Author's name05</a></p>
   <p><strong>28/08/2013&nbsp; &nbsp; </strong><a href="/link/paragraphs/bio03">Author's name06</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="/link/paragraphs/speech">Speech</a></p>
</div>
```

With beautifulsoap, I'm currently creating separate lists of times, speech authors, speech links,
links to biographies and then put them in a dictionary or dataframe. But I'm having difficulty with two things:

- (1) as you can see in the html example indicated above in some paragraphs it has the five information to be extracted and
  in other paragraphs only three pieces of information. with that, when it comes to combining the lists, it does not work. Would it be possible to iterate by paragraph and extract the internal information from each paragraph?
- (2) in the href links there are paragraphs with information to be extracted (I can do this), but I am having difficulty integrating this in the same dictionary indicated above

```py
url = 'www.example.com/'
html = urlopen(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')

for time in bs.find_all('strong'):
    times.append(times.get_text())

times_tmp2 = times[2:]
time_tmp2 = "".join([str(_) for _ in times_tmp2])
time_tmp2 = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", time_tmp2)
time_tmp2 = re.split("(\d{2}[-/]\d{2}[-/]\d{4})", time_tmp2)
time_tmp2 = [x for x in time_tmp2 if x != '']
time_tmp2 = [elem for elem in time_tmp2 if elem.strip()]
times_final = list(set(time_tmp2))


links_to_speech = []
for link in bs.find_all('a', string='Speech'):
    # print(urllib.parse.urljoin(url, link.get('href')))
    links_to_speech.append(urllib.parse.urljoin(url, link.get('href')))


authors = []
for author in bs.find_all('a'):
    authors.append(author.get_text())

authors_final = []
for author in authors:
    init = 'First Author'
    final = 'Not Author'
    index_init = authors.index(init)
    index_final = authors.index(final)
    a = autores[index_inito:index_final]
    a = [x for x in a if x != 'Speech']
    authors_final = a


links_bio = []
p = bs.find_all('p')
for link_bio in p:
    a = link_bio.find('a') 
    links_bio.append(a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the provided target data structure above, you appear to be using a dictionary. It isn't clear what you would like your keys to be so I would probably suggest using a list/array.

I would suggest a slightly different way to dissect the problem.One potential implementation would be to iterate over each row (paragraph `<p>` of the table (div `<div>`) and consume the data as it is present. This allows us to populate the `data` array one index at a time.

From here, if the link(s) are present you could then query the external data source (or read from a different location on the page) to collect the respective data. In the example below, I choose to do this in a different iteration of data to help make the code a bit more readable.

I have not used the [BeautifulSoap4](https://github.com/il-vladislav/BeautifulSoup4) library before. I apologise if my solution isn't the most elegant regarding the libraries usage.

```py
from typing import List
from urllib.request import urlopen

import bs4.element
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data: List = []  # <- we want the data here.

# Parse the webpage html
bs = BeautifulSoup('''\
<div class="item-page">
   <p><strong>TITLE</strong></p>
   <p><strong>18/05/2016</strong>&nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="/link//paragraphs/bio">Author's name</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="/link/paragraphs/speech">Speech</a></p>
   <p><strong>01/01/2011&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</strong><a href="/link/paragraphs/bio02">Author's name02</a></p>
   <p><strong>28/08/2013&nbsp; &nbsp; </strong><a href="/link/paragraphs/bio03">Author's name03</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="/link/paragraphs/speech">Speech</a></p>
   <p><strong>01/01/2011&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</strong><a href="/link/paragraphs/bio04">Author's name04</a></p>
   <p><strong>01/01/2011&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</strong><a href="/link/paragraphs/bio05">Author's name05</a></p>
   <p><strong>28/08/2013&nbsp; &nbsp; </strong><a href="/link/paragraphs/bio03">Author's name06</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="/link/paragraphs/speech">Speech</a></p>
</div>''', features='html.parser')

# Grab the paragraphs within the `item-page` div, checkout CSS selectors :).
entries = bs.select('div.item-page p')

# Populate the entries with time and links (if they are present)
for entry in entries:
    entry: bs4.element.Tag  # https://github.com/il-vladislav/BeautifulSoup4/blob/master/bs4/element.py

    time = entry.select_one('strong').get_text()
    if time == 'TITLE':
        continue  # skip this entry

    # Grab a list of the links (may be of size 0-2 depending on the contents).
    links = [link.get('href') for link in entry.select('a')]

    # Populate the array with a document.
    data.append({
        'time': time,
        'speech_link': links[0] if len(links) > 0 else '',
        'speech': [],
        'bio_link': links[1] if len(links) > 1 else '',
        'bio': [],
    })

# Collect speeches and bios if present.
for person in data:
    if person['speech_link']:  # empty strings evaluate as False and would be skipped.
        html = urlopen('https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras=2&start-with-lorem=1&format=html')
        person['speech'] = [para.get_text() for para in BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser').select('p')]

    if person['bio_link']:
        html = urlopen('https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras=2&start-with-lorem=1&format=html')
        person['bio'] = [para.get_text() for para in BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser').select('p')]

print(data)
```

Comment: thank you it worked here! could tell you why `authors = entry.select_one('a').get_text()` doesn't work, but `authors = bs.find('a').text` does? placed on the line above `time = entry.select_one('strong').get_text()`

Comment: Both methods appear to be functionally the same to me? The only difference between `select_one('a')` and `find('a')` is that select uses a CSS selector.

Pasting the below within the for loop body (line 35) yields no output.

```python3
if entry.select_one('a').get_text() != entry.find('a').text:
    print('difference!')
```

Comment: thanks @zag-scott! I still have some questions about the behavior to extract the "Author's name". In the link below I put a repl with annotations of doubts between lines 25 and 38, in case you want to take a look. https://replit.com/@RafaelA_/beautifulsoap-stackoverflow#main.py